# Comments please on my script - how to make it more efficient

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (SYS_Holidays) that have start and end dates of each holiday period. I need to output all holiday dates in a relational form. For example, I have 25-Dec-2017 to 2-Jan-2018 as one row in the input, I want to output 25-Dec, 26-Dec ... through 2-Jan as 9 rows.

I have written this script, could you please tell me how I can make it more efficient?

```
SELECT 
    H.HolidayName
    , DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, H.StartDate) AS HolidayDate
FROM 
    SYS_Holidays AS H
    CROSS JOIN Config_Numbers AS N 
WHERE 
    -- Figure the # of days between start and end: one row for each holiday-date
    -- If EndDate is null, just use StartDate (i.e. 1-day holiday)
    N.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, H.StartDate, ISNULL(H.EndDate, H.StartDate) ) + 1
```

NB: Config_Numbers is a table I have created with a *huge* list of integers (as BIGINT)

Comment: `BIGINT`? Unless your numbers table really contains over 2 billion numbers, that's unnecessary, and if it does contain over 2 billion numbers, it's excessive. For your purposes even 1000 would do if your query never crosses a year boundary; 1M is enough in almost all scenarios where you can realistically use a numbers table. At the very least, though, I should have its primary key on `N`. Does it?

Comment: Why a cross join and not an inner join? I guess the optimizer could end up with the same plan, but I would at least try it as an inner join in stead

Comment: Note that his approach is needlessly fancy to begin with, if we're talking public holidays. Only few holidays are multiple days, and for those that are it's hardly an imposition to give each date its own row. Since some holidays vary their position per year (e.g. Easter) a table of dates that has different dates per year is nearly inescapable anyway. A table with unique dates is about as efficient as you can get, for querying purposes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Yes, it has primary key on `N.Number`, and thanks for your advise, I have now downgraded it to INT. The highest number is 3M. For some reason, attempts to perform `DELETE FROM Config_Numbers WHERE Number > 10485756;` does not reduce it down, nor does it throw any error message. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because `10485756` is bigger than `3000000`. :-P There's no need for binary numbers here, such a table is supposed to be used in queries written by humans. One round million will do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : yes, of course, `10485756` is bigger than 3M

Comment: @JeroenMostert : the Christmas/New Year holiday is only an example. I work for a school, where the academic year-end can be a few months long. I figured if I can get it to work for 9 days, it will work for 60 days. Moreover, I need this to operate on historical records, where applications and stored procedures need to work on the old data, so I prefer not to add new rows

Comment: @SørenKongstad : Just modified it to an inner join, subtree cost is identical to the cross join case (225.875). The modified script is `SELECT 
    H.HolidayName
    , DATEADD(DAY, Number-1, H.StartDate) AS HolidayDate
FROM 
    SYS_Holidays AS H
    INNER JOIN Config_Numbers AS N ON N.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, H.StartDate, ISNULL(H.EndDate, H.StartDate) ) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using a date table and an inner join. Use the subquery to make a table if it is not efficient enough:

```
Create table #Test (HolidayName nvarchar(100), StartDate Date, EndDate Date)

Insert Into #Test Values ('Christmas', '2017-12-22', '2018-01-03'), ('Easter' , '2017-04-10', '2017-04-16')

SELECT HolidayName, DatesList.[Date] as HolidayDate
FROM #Test t
inner join (
    SELECT cast(dateadd(day, number, '2017-1-1') as date) as [Date]
     FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number < 1000) AS DatesList 
        on t.StartDate<=DatesList.[Date] and t.EndDate>=DatesList.[Date]
```

Comment: Very interesting approach... Subtree cost on the same table `SYS_Holidays` was substantially lower: 0.0643-ish. No need to use `Config_Numbers`. However, master..spt_values has an upper limit of 2048. Any ideas on how to make it higher (6000 will be better)?

Comment: So, when should I use my own numbers table (e.g. `Config_Numbers` in above), and when should I use `master..spt_values`, other than the obvious limitation of 2048?

Comment: @Muhammad Could change the subquery to SELECT cast(dateadd(day, number*10 + n, '2017-1-1') as date) as [Date]
     FROM master..spt_values
  cross join (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) a(n)
  WHERE type='P' and number < 20000

Comment: @Muhammad Your number table could replace master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number < 1000

Answer (score 0):

I modified @cloudsafe's answer, to yield the code below. It is still *much* faster than any of the joins using `Config_Numbers`. Subtree cost came to ~0.2785.

I figured that 2048 can cover a little more than 5 years, so I broke my code up into 5-year blocks, and did a UNION to join them up.

Trouble is, I'd have to remember to do another UNION every 5-years :-(

```
SELECT HolidayName, DatesList.[Date] as HolidayDate
FROM SYS_Holidays AS H
inner join (
    SELECT cast(dateadd(day, number, '2013-01-01') as date) as [Date]
     FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number < 2048) AS DatesList 
        on H.StartDate <= DatesList.[Date] and H.EndDate >=DatesList.[Date]

UNION

SELECT HolidayName, DatesList.[Date] as HolidayDate, H.HolidayId, H.CampusId, H.CategoryId
FROM SYS_Holidays AS H
inner join (
    SELECT cast(dateadd(day, number, '2018-01-01') as date) as [Date]
     FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number < 2048) AS DatesList 
        on H.StartDate <= DatesList.[Date] and H.EndDate >=DatesList.[Date]
```

Any further suggestions for improvement, please?

Comment: Here's one: don't use `spt_values`, use your own numbers table. For one, `spt_values` is undocumented, for another, doing cross-database queries takes locks you don't want. An on-the-fly recursive CTE is an alternative if you really don't want a numbers table, but a numbers table usually gives better perf. [See also](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/97345).